# Using typescript in Electron's preload scripts

Tags: typescript, electron

I build an Electron application using electron-forge's react-typescript template, meaning it uses electron-prebuilt-compile, which according to [the only documentation I can find](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile) is supposed to just work.

The index.html contains typescript that just works, as advertised. But I am also using a [webview tag](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) with a preload script, in order to display external websites and modify them. This is the code I'm using:

```
<webview id="webview" preload="./preload.ts" webpreferences="contextIsolation, webSecurity=no" src="https://example.com"></webview>
```

This preload script is rather involved, and I would love to use typescript for it. But it is apparently parsed as javascript, with any type annotations leading to syntax errors. Is there a trick to make this work with typescript? If I have to call the transpiler manually, how do I integrate this with electron-forge's build process?

**tl;dr**: preload script is parsed as javascript despite typescript "just working" everywhere else, I would like to use typescript here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preload script is different kind, you can't directly point typescript in there. Only possible way is make javascript preload script which `bootstraps` electron compile inside of it (since you are using electron-prebuilt-compile), and require typescript files inside of it. It is somewhat verbose and require additional overhead into, I honestly not strongly recommend for it.

Comment: That's somewhat disappointing, but I feared as much. I am somewhat unsure how to bootstrap electron-compile. https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/wiki/Using-'preload'-scripts describes an approach that just ends with `Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': [...] Elements cannot be registered from extensions`. Do you have any insight how to do this, or should I rather open a new question for that error?

Comment: fixed that problem, contextIsolation was creating the error. Without it,the previously mentioned wiki entry works

Answer (score 5):

You can use TypeScript in a preload file (or any file). Just import the [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) package and configure it before you import any of your TypeScript code.

F.e., make an `index.js` file containing:

```js
require('./require-hooks')
module.exports = require('./entry') // this is your TypeScript entry point.
```

then in your `require-hooks.js` file configure ts-node (ts-node is a require hook that compiles TypeScript on the fly, with caching for subsequent runs):

```js
// ability to require/import TypeScript files
require('ts-node').register({
  typeCheck: false, // faster, no type checking when require'ing files. Use another process to do actual type checking.
  transpileOnly: true, // no type checking, just strip types and output JS.
  files: true,

  // manually supply our own compilerOptions, otherwise if we run this file
  // from another project's location then ts-node will use
  // the compilerOptions from that other location, which may not work.
  compilerOptions: require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions,
})
```

Note, you can put all sorts of require hooks in there, for example so you can do things like `require('path/to/file.ts')`,  `require('path/to/file.tsx')`,  `require('path/to/file.jsx')`,  `require('path/to/file.png')`,  `require('path/to/file.mp3')`, etc, where you can define hooks for handling certain types of files (similar to Webpack in some way, but hooking into Node's builtin `require` function). For example, [`@babel/register`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/register) is a hook for running JS files through Babel, [`asset-require-hook`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asset-require-hook) is a require hook that allows you to import assets like JPG files, [`yaml-hook`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-hook) allows you to `require` `.yaml` files. EDIT: Even more: [`css-modules-require-hook`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-modules-require-hook) for importing CSS modules, and [`module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) for creating aliases like with WebPack.

The [`pirates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pirates) lib is a popular tool for making your own require hooks, though I also find it easy to make hooks manually without a library. You can, for example, override `Module.prototype.require` to implement some simple hooks:

```js
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
const Module = require('module')
const oldRequire = Module.prototype.require

function toFileURL(filePath) {
  return url.format({
    pathname: filePath,
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
  })
}

Module.prototype.require = function(moduleIdentifier) {
  // this simple hook returns a `file://...` URL when you try to `require()`
  // a file with extension obj, svg, png, or jpg.
  if (['.obj', '.png', '.svg', '.jpg'].some(ext => moduleIdentifier.endsWith(ext))) {
    const result = String(toFileURL(path.resolve(path.dirname(this.filename), moduleIdentifier)))

    result.default = result
    return result
  } else {
    return oldRequire.call(this, moduleIdentifier)
  }
}
```

then in some other file,

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const img = require('path/to/foo.jpg')

console.log(img) // file:///absolute/path/to/foo.jpg
document.createElement('img').src = img
```

You could even move the call to `document.createElement('img').src = img` into your overridden `require` method to do it automatically and return the `img` element instead of returning a `file://` URL. :)

Finally, in your `./entry.ts` file that the above `index.js` file imports, you can have any TypeScript in there.

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to add a 2nd webpack configuration that outputs a single `inject.js` file.

`src/inject.ts` transpiles into => `dist/inject.js` from where it can be required like this:

```
new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      sandbox: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'mercari_inject.js')
    }
});
```

given a base config `webpack.main.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    ...
}
```

the main config `webpack.main.config.js` should look like this:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config');

const mainConfig = merge.smart(baseConfig, {...})
const injectScriptConfig = merge.smart(baseConfig, {
  target: 'electron-preload',
  entry: {
    inject: './src/inject.ts',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
       ... // babel/typescript loaders
    ]
  } 
})

module.exports = [
   mainConfig,
   injectScriptConfig,
]
```

notice that before the export changes from a single configuration object to an array.

```
module.exports = {...}
module.exports = [{...}, {...}]
```